# Yet another shared pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel, pointers

What might be wrong with this shared pointer? One good point of it might be, that it should handle array types correctly by default (e.g. `light_ptr<int[]>(new int[10])`.

`std::shared_ptr` has the advantage of being more portable. For example, `emscripten` provides an implementation, but `light_ptr` won't compile, still, it can be ported to `emscripten` easily. The native implementation may also be more optimized.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef LIGHTPTR_HPP
# define LIGHTPTR_HPP

#include <cassert>

#include <atomic>

#include <memory>

#include <utility>

#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
  using counter_type = ::std::size_t;

  using atomic_type = ::std::atomic<counter_type>;

  template <typename T>
  using deleter_type = void (*)(T*);

  template <typename U>
  struct ref_type
  {
    using type = U&;
  };

  template <>
  struct ref_type<void>
  {
    using type = void;
  };

  template <typename T>
  inline void dec_ref(atomic_type* const counter_ptr,
    T* const ptr, deleter_type<T> const deleter)
  {
    if (counter_ptr && (counter_type(1) ==
      counter_ptr->fetch_sub(counter_type(1), ::std::memory_order_relaxed)))
    {
      delete counter_ptr;

      deleter(ptr);
    }
    // else do nothing
  }

  inline void inc_ref(atomic_type* const counter_ptr)
  {
    assert(counter_ptr);
    counter_ptr->fetch_add(counter_type(1), ::std::memory_order_relaxed);
  }
}

template <typename T>
struct light_ptr
{
  template <typename U, typename V>
  struct deletion_type
  {
    using type = V;
  };

  template <typename U, typename V>
  struct deletion_type<U[], V>
  {
    using type = V[];
  };

  template <typename U, typename V, ::std::size_t N>
  struct deletion_type<U[N], V>
  {
    using type = V[];
  };

  template <typename U>
  struct remove_array
  {
    using type = U;
  };

  template <typename U>
  struct remove_array<U[]>
  {
    using type = U;
  };

  template <typename U, ::std::size_t N>
  struct remove_array<U[N]>
  {
    using type = U;
  };

  using element_type = typename remove_array<T>::type;

  using deleter_type = ::detail::deleter_type<element_type>;

  light_ptr() = default;

  template <typename U>
  explicit light_ptr(U* const p,
    deleter_type const d = default_deleter<U>)
  {
    reset(p, d);
  }

  ~light_ptr() { ::detail::dec_ref(counter_ptr_, ptr_, deleter_); }

  light_ptr(light_ptr const& other) { *this = other; }

  light_ptr(light_ptr&& other) noexcept { *this = ::std::move(other); }

  light_ptr& operator=(light_ptr const& rhs)
  {
    if (*this != rhs)
    {
      ::detail::dec_ref(counter_ptr_, ptr_, deleter_);

      counter_ptr_ = rhs.counter_ptr_;
      ptr_ = rhs.ptr_;

      deleter_ = rhs.deleter_;

      ::detail::inc_ref(counter_ptr_);
    }
    // else do nothing

    return *this;
  }

  light_ptr& operator=(light_ptr&& rhs) noexcept
  {
    if (*this != rhs)
    {
      counter_ptr_ = rhs.counter_ptr_;
      ptr_ = rhs.ptr_;

      deleter_ = rhs.deleter_;

      rhs.counter_ptr_ = nullptr;
      rhs.ptr_ = nullptr;
    }
    // else do nothing

    return *this;
  }

  bool operator<(light_ptr const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return get() < rhs.get();
  }

  bool operator==(light_ptr const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return counter_ptr_ == rhs.counter_ptr_;
  }

  bool operator!=(light_ptr const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return !operator==(rhs);
  }

  bool operator==(::std::nullptr_t const) const noexcept
  {
    return !ptr_;
  }

  bool operator!=(::std::nullptr_t const) const noexcept
  {
    return ptr_;
  }

  explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return ptr_; }

  typename ::detail::ref_type<T>::type
  operator*() const noexcept
  {
    return *static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(ptr_));
  }

  T* operator->() const noexcept
  {
    return static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(ptr_));
  }

  element_type* get() const noexcept { return ptr_; }

  void reset() { reset(nullptr); }

  void reset(::std::nullptr_t const)
  {
    ::detail::dec_ref(counter_ptr_, ptr_, deleter_);

    counter_ptr_ = nullptr;
    ptr_ = nullptr;
  }

  template <typename U>
  void reset(U* const p, deleter_type const d = default_deleter<U>)
  {
    ::detail::dec_ref(counter_ptr_, ptr_, deleter_);

    counter_ptr_ = new ::detail::atomic_type(::detail::counter_type(1));
    ptr_ = p;

    deleter_ = d;
  }

  void swap(light_ptr& other) noexcept
  {
    ::std::swap(counter_ptr_, other.counter_ptr_);
    ::std::swap(ptr_, other.ptr_);
    ::std::swap(deleter_, other.deleter_);
  }

  bool unique() const noexcept
  {
    return ::detail::counter_type(1) == use_count();
  }

  ::detail::counter_type use_count() const noexcept
  {
    return counter_ptr_ ?
      counter_ptr_->load(::std::memory_order_relaxed) :
      ::detail::counter_type{};
  }

  template <typename U>
  static void default_deleter(element_type* const p)
  {
    ::std::default_delete<typename deletion_type<T, U>::type>()(
      static_cast<U*>(p));
  }

private:
  ::detail::atomic_type* counter_ptr_{};

  element_type* ptr_{};

  deleter_type deleter_;
};

template<class T, class ...Args>
inline light_ptr<T> make_light(Args&& ...args)
{
  return light_ptr<T>(new T(::std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

namespace std
{
  template <typename T>
  struct hash<light_ptr<T> >
  {
    size_t operator()(light_ptr<T> const& l) const noexcept
    {
      return hash<typename light_ptr<T>::element_type*>(l.get());
    }
  };
}

#endif // LIGHTPTR_HPP
```

**Usage:**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <thread>

#include <vector>

#include "lightptr.hpp"

int main()
{
  {
    light_ptr<int> p(new int);

    *p = 10;

    light_ptr<int> s(p);

    p.reset(new int);

    std::cout << s.use_count() << ": " << *s << std::endl;

    std::vector<light_ptr<float> > v(1000000);

    for (auto& r: v)
    {
      r.reset(new float);

      *r = 100;
    }

    auto a(make_light<char[4]>());

    (*a)[2] = 10;
    a.get()[3] = 10;

    ::std::thread a_([&p]{light_ptr<int> a(p); std::cout << p.use_count() << std::endl;});
    ::std::thread b_([&p]{light_ptr<int> a(p); std::cout << p.use_count() << std::endl;});
    ::std::thread c_([&p]{light_ptr<int> a(p); std::cout << p.use_count() << std::endl;});
    ::std::thread d_([&p]{light_ptr<int> a(p); std::cout << p.use_count() << std::endl;});
    ::std::thread e_([&p]{light_ptr<int> a(p); std::cout << p.use_count() << std::endl;});
    ::std::thread f_([&p]{light_ptr<int> a(p); std::cout << p.use_count() << std::endl;});
    ::std::thread g_([&p]{light_ptr<int> a(p); std::cout << p.use_count() << std::endl;});
    ::std::thread h_([&p]{light_ptr<int> a(p); std::cout << p.use_count() << std::endl;});

    a_.join(); b_.join(); c_.join(); d_.join();
    e_.join(); f_.join(); g_.join(); h_.join();
  }

  struct A
  {
    ~A() { std::cout << "deleted" << std::endl; }
  };

  light_ptr<void> a(new A);

  light_ptr<A[]> b(new A[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Writing your own shared pointer is a bad idea. It is a lot harder than you think to just get it working correctly. Optimizing is a step on top of that. But making it work should be your priority. PS. The standard one does not use any compiler specific tricks.

Comment: However, I can point out one thing (so far): you're using two different header guards.  I'd remove the `#pragma once` while keeping the other.

Comment: @Jamal That's a backup for compilers that don't support the `#pragma once`.

Comment: @user1095108: In that case you are stacking them wrong. Put the pragma inside the other header-guard.

Comment: @Deduplicator I've read somewhere that `#pragma once` is faster of the two header guards. That's why I put it first, since otherwise I would defeat the purpose why I use both header guards. There seems to be nothing wrong, if one uses both.

Comment: Both are of equal speed if implemented properly. But the standard `#ifndef`-Guards optimisation heavily depends on the guards actually bracketing *the whole file*, while that's not the case for `#pragma once`. Anyway, if there was a speed difference the same would still hold, please read up on how they work / can be optimised / are optimised.

Answer (score 4):

The move assignment operator is broken:

```
light_ptr& operator=(light_ptr&& rhs) noexcept
```

You over write the current members with the values from the rhs, but do not decrement the reference counter before overwriting. It might be easier to swap `*this` with `rhs`.

Don't include types that are not being used:

```
  template <typename U, typename V, ::std::size_t N>
  struct deletion_type<U[N], V>
  {
    using type = V[];
  };

  template <typename U, ::std::size_t N>
  struct remove_array<U[N]>
  {
    using type = U;
  };
```

Casting to void*. Once this is done the only valid operation is to cast back to the original type. Annything else is undefined.

```
 return static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(ptr_));
```

In this case `element_type*` is the same as `T*`. But the code is written in such a way that any changes by a maintainer can easily result in this being not true. Also I don;t actually see the need for a cast.