# One more shared pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Here's a (hopefully) better shared pointer than the previous one. The improvement is that now it should also accept function and lambda objects. Should work fine with threads.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef LIGHTPTR_HPP
# define LIGHTPTR_HPP

#include <cassert>

#include <atomic>

#include <memory>

#include <utility>

#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
  using counter_type = unsigned;

  using atomic_type = ::std::atomic<counter_type>;

  template <typename T>
  using deleter_type = void (*)(T*);

  template <typename U>
  struct ref_type
  {
    using type = U&;
  };

  template <>
  struct ref_type<void>
  {
    using type = void;
  };
}

template <typename T>
struct light_ptr
{
  template <typename U, typename V>
  struct deletion_type
  {
    using type = V;
  };

  template <typename U, typename V>
  struct deletion_type<U[], V>
  {
    using type = V[];
  };

  template <typename U, typename V, ::std::size_t N>
  struct deletion_type<U[N], V>
  {
    using type = V[];
  };

  template <typename U>
  struct remove_array
  {
    using type = U;
  };

  template <typename U>
  struct remove_array<U[]>
  {
    using type = U;
  };

  template <typename U, ::std::size_t N>
  struct remove_array<U[N]>
  {
    using type = U;
  };

  using element_type = typename remove_array<T>::type;

  using deleter_type = detail::deleter_type<element_type>;

  struct counter_base
  {
    using invoker_type = void (*)(counter_base*, element_type*);

    explicit counter_base(detail::counter_type c,
      invoker_type invoker) noexcept :
      counter_(c),
      invoker_(invoker)
    {
    }

    template <typename U>
    typename ::std::enable_if<!::std::is_void<U>{}>::type
    dec_ref(U* const ptr)
    {
      if (detail::counter_type(1) ==
        counter_.fetch_sub(detail::counter_type(1),
          ::std::memory_order_relaxed))
      {
        typedef char type_must_be_complete[sizeof(U) ? 1 : -1];
        (void)sizeof(type_must_be_complete);
        invoker_(this, ptr);
      }
      // else do nothing
    }

    template <typename U>
    typename ::std::enable_if<::std::is_void<U>{}>::type
    dec_ref(U* const ptr)
    {
      if (detail::counter_type(1) ==
        counter_.fetch_sub(detail::counter_type(1),
          ::std::memory_order_relaxed))
      {
        invoker_(this, ptr);
      }
      // else do nothing
    }

    void inc_ref() noexcept
    {
      //assert(counter_ptr);
      counter_.fetch_add(detail::counter_type(1),
        ::std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    detail::atomic_type counter_{};

    invoker_type invoker_;
  };

  template <typename U>
  struct counter : counter_base
  {
    explicit counter(detail::counter_type const c, U&& d) :
      counter_base(c, invoker),
      d_(::std::forward<U>(d))
    {
    }

  private:
    static void invoker(counter_base* const ptr, element_type* e)
    {
      auto const c(static_cast<counter<U>*>(ptr));

      typename ::std::decay<U>::type const d(::std::move(c->d_));

      delete c;

      d(e);
    }

  private:
    typename ::std::decay<U>::type const d_;
  };

  light_ptr() = default;

  template <typename U>
  explicit light_ptr(U* p)
  {
    reset(p);
  }

  template <typename U, typename D>
  explicit light_ptr(U* p, D&& d)
  {
    reset(p, ::std::forward<D>(d));
  }

  ~light_ptr()
  {
    if (counter_)
    {
      counter_->dec_ref(ptr_);
    }
    // else do nothing
  }

  light_ptr(light_ptr const& other) { *this = other; }

  light_ptr(light_ptr&& other) noexcept { *this = ::std::move(other); }

  light_ptr& operator=(light_ptr const& rhs)
  {
    if (*this != rhs)
    {
      if (counter_)
      {
        counter_->dec_ref(ptr_);
      }
      // else do nothing

      counter_ = rhs.counter_;
      ptr_ = rhs.ptr_;

      if (counter_)
      {
        counter_->inc_ref();
      }
      // else do nothing
    }
    // else do nothing

    return *this;
  }

  light_ptr& operator=(light_ptr&& rhs) noexcept
  {
    counter_ = rhs.counter_;
    ptr_ = rhs.ptr_;

    rhs.counter_ = nullptr;
    rhs.ptr_ = nullptr;

    return *this;
  }

  light_ptr& operator=(::std::nullptr_t const) noexcept { reset(); }

  bool operator<(light_ptr const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return get() < rhs.get();
  }

  bool operator==(light_ptr const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return counter_ == rhs.counter_;
  }

  bool operator!=(light_ptr const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return !operator==(rhs);
  }

  bool operator==(::std::nullptr_t const) const noexcept
  {
    return !ptr_;
  }

  bool operator!=(::std::nullptr_t const) const noexcept
  {
    return ptr_;
  }

  explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return ptr_; }

  typename detail::ref_type<T>::type
  operator*() const noexcept
  {
    return *static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(ptr_));
  }

  T* operator->() const noexcept
  {
    return static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(ptr_));
  }

  element_type* get() const noexcept { return ptr_; }

  void reset() { reset(nullptr); }

  void reset(::std::nullptr_t const)
  {
    if (counter_)
    {
      counter_->dec_ref(ptr_);

      counter_ = {};
    }
    // else do nothing

    ptr_ = {};
  }

  template <typename U>
  void reset(U* const p)
  {
    reset(p, [](element_type* const p) {
      ::std::default_delete<typename deletion_type<T, U>::type>()(
        static_cast<U*>(p));
      });
  }

  template <typename U, typename D>
  void reset(U* const p, D&& d)
  {
    if (counter_)
    {
      counter_->dec_ref(ptr_);
    }
    // else do nothing

    counter_ = new counter<D>(detail::counter_type(1), ::std::forward<D>(d));

    ptr_ = p;
  }

  void swap(light_ptr& other) noexcept
  {
    ::std::swap(counter_, other.counter_);
    ::std::swap(ptr_, other.ptr_);
  }

  bool unique() const noexcept
  {
    return detail::counter_type(1) == use_count();
  }

  detail::counter_type use_count() const noexcept
  {
    return counter_ ?
      counter_->counter_.load(::std::memory_order_relaxed) :
      detail::counter_type{};
  }

private:
  counter_base* counter_{};

  element_type* ptr_{};
};

template<class T, class ...Args>
inline light_ptr<T> make_light(Args&& ...args)
{
  return light_ptr<T>(new T(::std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

namespace std
{
  template <typename T>
  struct hash<::generic::light_ptr<T> >
  {
    size_t operator()(::generic::light_ptr<T> const& l) const noexcept
    {
      return hash<typename ::generic::light_ptr<T>::element_type*>()(l.get());
    }
  };
}

#endif // LIGHTPTR_HPP
```

Usage is the same as for my [previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30398/yet-another-shared-pointer) shared pointer. Improvements?

EDIT: Loki threads issue is wrong. Look here for [explanation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety). His example is one boost defines as UB.

Comment: Just a comment: Must you be so free with vertical space?

Comment: You mean, there's too much line spacing? Just a personal preference.

Comment: No. My point in it being broken for threading still holds. You have not proven otherwise and I provide a compelling example of how easily it will break. Fortunately for us the std::shared_ptr is **not broken** in shared environments (Your link).

Comment: Your example shows canonical UB from the link I've provided (`reset` from one thread and copy from another, which is read/write access from different threads, which results in UB).

Comment: @LokiAstari Also, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491812/boostshared-ptr-is-it-safe-to-use-it-in-multiple-threads .

Comment: @user1095108: Are you trying to say that your implementation above is a copy of boost::shared_ptr? I believe boost::shared_ptr is thread safe. The check (and example) I provided below lead me to believe your version is not thread safe. If I am wrong please explain what part of my example falls down. As far as I can tell the example holds and your light_ptr is broken.

Comment: @LokiAstari Your example holds, but it also holds for both `std::shared_ptr` and `boost::shared_ptr`, that is, `boost::shared_ptr` is 100% broken and `std::shared_ptr` _may_ be broken (no guarantees in the standard). Your locking idea is outside of `c++` philosophy, which says, that you pay for only what you use, i.e. locking outside of the shared pointer, remains a possibility, if you want it.

Comment: @user1095108: The link [**you** provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11492094/14065) says the exact opposite. It says **Different shared_ptr instances can be "written to" simultaneosly by multiple threads** read the full quote the other side of the link. Your code is not safe in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: @user1095108: The point is. If you don't like me conclusion your are free to ignore them. But writing shared pointer is hard (even for me) in a single threaded environment. Writing them for mulch-threaded environments (which you are implying by using atomic members) is much harder than that. Concentrate on a working single threaded version first. Then stop trying to be clever for multi-threaded and lock down your object.

Comment: @user1095108: To make it work in a multithreaded environment. Its not just the inc/dec of an integer that must be atomic. It is the "decrement and setting the pointer to NULL if you reach zero" must be an atomic operation. You can delete the object after the object after that.

Comment: Exactly, but what you are doing is read/write. One thread is writing (reset), the other reading/writing (by copying) and that's UB, literally from the examples in `boost` docs. You can't mix read/write.

Answer (score 3):

Lets the obligatory (**this is not a good idea**) out of the way.

I don't like you cramming all the code together into a single header definition. It makes it hard to see the interface. Yes the standard library do it this way but they are so heavily documented that they don't need to break it apart. Your code is not documented so I need to be able to distinguish the interface.

Its not hard to break the declaration and the definition into different parts of the file:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        void myInt1();
        int  myInt2();
    private:
        Data data;
};

inline void MyClass::myInt1()
{
}

inline int MyClass::myInt2()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Basically I want to be able to see the class declaration in one screen (so I can see what variables need to be initialized when doing a review). I can also quickly gauge and see the public interface (when using the class).

Lets also put all the constructors together. So I don't have to search in multiple parts of your class for the different constructors.

```
  light_ptr() = default;

  template <typename U>
  explicit light_ptr(U* p);

  template <typename U, typename D>
  explicit light_ptr(U* p, D&& d);

  ~light_ptr();

  light_ptr(light_ptr const& other);

  light_ptr(light_ptr&& other) noexcept;

  light_ptr& operator=(light_ptr const& rhs);

  light_ptr& operator=(light_ptr&& rhs) noexcept;

  light_ptr& operator=(::std::nullptr_t const) noexcept;
```

For some reason your destructor is in the middle. So you have some constructors on either side.

Copy constructor:

```
light_ptr(light_ptr const& other) { *this = other; }
```

That's not the copy and swap idiom (seems to be the inverse). May throw a few people. If you are not going to use standard idioms them you should have a go at explaining why.

Not sure this is helpeful:

```
// else do nothing
```

I can see that there is no else. You are just asking for trouble when the code goes out of sync with the comments. Comments are for describing **why** you are doing something. There is no point in describing the code with comments the code should be readable by-itself the code describes what it is doing.

You go to all the effort of making the counter inside counter_base atomic. But this is a complete false sense of security as the `counter_` variable inside `light_ptr` is not atomic or protected in any way. Also there is no checking of the counter when accessing the element so you can just as easily hand off an invalid pointer.

```
// Main Thread.
light_ptr<MyType>   data(new MyType);


     Thread1                                           Thread2
     data.reset();                                     light_ptr<MyType>  tmp(data);

     void reset(::std::nullptr_t const)
     {
         if (counter_)
         {
             counter_->dec_ref(ptr_);

             // Thread is swapped out here.
             // counter is 0 and ptr has been de-allocated.
             // But has not been nulled out:


                                                       light_ptr& operator=(light_ptr const& rhs)
                                                       {
                                                           if (*this != rhs)
                                                           {
                                                             // This side is NULL so this condition can be ignored.
                                                             if (counter_)
                                                             {
                                                               counter_->dec_ref(ptr_);
                                                             }


                                                             // Use the counter from (data) which happens to currently be 0 but is valid.
                                                             counter_ = rhs.counter_;
                                                             // Get a copy of rhs pointer (which is invalid as it has already been free'ed)
                                                             ptr_ = rhs.ptr_;

                                                             // Now we increment the counter. As the pointer is still valid.
                                                             if (counter_)
                                                             {
                                                               counter_->inc_ref();
                                                             }
                                                           }
                                                           // So we now have a count of 1. With a pointer to an invalid piece of memoy.
                                                           return *this;
                                                       }

             // Reset the local counter.
             counter_ = {};
         }

         // Reset the local ptr.
         ptr_ = {};
     }
```

Why the difference here:

```
  bool operator<(light_ptr const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return get() < rhs.get();         // Why are we using the ptr here
  }

  bool operator==(light_ptr const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return counter_ == rhs.counter_;  // And the counter here?
  }
```

I would be more consistent.

```
 Example of inconistent behavior:

 std::set<light_ptr<MyType>>  set;
 MyType*   data = new MyType;
 set.emplace(data);
 set.emplace(data);
 std::cout << set.size() << "\n";  // Prints 1
                                   // As the values are considered euqal.
                                   // As we use operator< for comparison
                                   // and equality.

 std::unordered_set<light_ptr<MyType>>  set1;
 set1.emplace(data);
 set1.emplace(data);
 std::cout << set1.size() << "\n"; // Prints 2
                                   // As the values are not considered euqal.
                                   // They hash to the same bucket.
                                   // But because they have unique counter_ objects
                                   // They are not equal and thus result in different
                                   // results.
```

Maybe the difference is not a big issue as you are going to crash with a double delete anyway. But you break the principle of least surprise by doing it differently.

Comment: for the relational operators: one can initialize 2 shared pointers with the same pointer - it is a bug, as a double delete will occur. but the shared pointers should not compare equal, in my opinion.

Comment: @user1095108: And they would not if you used counter in both cases. The trouble with your implementation is that they will be compared equal when placed in an associative container (which just uses `operator<`) So you will have one object copy over the other.

Comment: Imho it doesn't matter how to smart-pointers pointing to the same object which do not cooperate compare: That is a bug there already.

Comment: @LokiAstari for the threads: can you rework your example: I don't see where `reset(nullptr)` is called.

Comment: Comment to include guards: If you use both, stack them the other way around for better effect.

Comment: @LokiAstari I think associative containers use _either_ `operator==` (the unordered ones) or `operator<` (ordered ones), not both. Not a bug therefore, but a good point anyways.

Comment: @user1095108: SO you get different results/behaviors if you use different container types. That is even worse.

Comment: @LokiAstari That's always the case, as unordered containers have no order. You cannot say how they will order elements in advance.

Comment: @user1095108: You seem to be missing the point completely. Lets just say it broken and leave it at that. Its not going to work correctly in most situations. At best you will break the principle of least surprise at worst you will get different behaviors if you change a class to have a different type of associative container. Neither is good.

Comment: Ok, the threads bug is a good one, I'll have to ponder on it for a little while more. As for the copy and swap idiom, why use it? I mean, it is not obligatory for working code.

Comment: I did not say that you had to use. I just said you had to explain why you are not using it. Idioms are standard ways of doing things. If you move away from the standard ways of doing things you should explain why you think you are so special. Everybody else is going to go poo he can;t even use the normal idioms this must be bad. It may be that you have a perfectly good reason for doing something but you need to explain it (we can not deduce why you choose to stray from the standard).

Comment: @LokiAstari Any yet you are wrong, even about the threads. I have done my homework well, see here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety . You want something even `boost` does not support, i.e. simultaneous read/write access from multiple threads, support for which is omitted for performance reasons. You should update your answer to take this into account.

Comment: @LokiAstari As for the copy-and-swap idiom: I was merely under impression, that it was a `c++03` thing, before `rvalue references` came about.

Comment: @LokiAstari Also, your `set` example shows precisely what I want to achieve: that 2 shared pointers, initialized with the same pointer, don't compare equal.

Comment: @user1095108: But my examples shows that also do compare equal when used in a different type if container.

Comment: @LokiAstari Anyway, the reason why `operator==` is wrong is the hash calculation, as it is not based on counter_, but on the contained pointer. That's a true bug. You are wrong about the threads, though, please fix your answer.

Comment: @user1095108: The problem has nothing to do with your hash function. But the difference between `operator<` and `operator==`

Comment: @user1095108: Wrong. Possible. But I think you will have to prove it. But I may have been mistaken in how broken it is. Not only was the ptr deallocated but also the counter object. So you are now actually invoking undefined behavior when trying to increment it in the second thread.